# Vim : Error detected while processing function <SNR>20_ActivateBuffer

Tags: vim

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4

Error detected while processing function 20_ActivateBuffer:
line    6:
E684: list index out of range: 1
Press ENTER or type command to continue

Comment: voted to close.. don't know what are you asking....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is probably caused by the BufExplorer plugin.  Update to the latest version of BufExplorer and see if that fixes the problem.  See http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Fwd-E684-error-when-changing-buffers-td4753709.html.